# Escaping backslashes in a string?

Tags: c++, regex, string, escaping

I'm a fairly new C/C++ programmer and I've been having this issue with escaping. I don't know if my string is being escaped or not. It's hard to explain...

For example:

```
wchar_t* getpathAppDataLocal = 0;
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &getpathAppDataLocal);

wstringstream apdlcl(getpathAppDataLocal);
std::cout << apdlcl.str();
```

The output of this gives me: `"C:\Users\whatever\AppData\Local\"`

Does this mean that the backslashes are already escaped? Or do I have to somehow escape them so I can use `apdlcl.str()` for something like `boost::filesystem::whatever`?

Comment: I'm coding in C++. I included C++ in the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your backslashes are definitely literal backslashes. Backslashes only act to create escape sequences in string literals (i.e., strings you explicitly write out in your code, such as `const char *s= "Hello World!\n"`).

Comment: And for character literals `'\n'`.